# CSS : Align characters to vertical

Tags: css

How can I align each character to vertical by using css ?

```
<div>VALUES</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't seem to understand why all these answers are being downvoted. They all address the question somehow asked by OP.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Not all of them. The `rotate` approach will rotate the entire div, so the characters will be rotated as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Use writing-mode and text-orientation properties**

```css
 div 
 {
 writing-mode: vertical-rl;
 text-orientation: upright;
  }
```

```html
<div>VALUES</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) and [`text-orientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation) properties as follows:

```css
div {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
}
```

```html
<div>VALUES</div>
```